# PHP reply-to email id doesn't show properly

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

This is my email.php page coding. Now i'm getting the mail from contact form. But, i can't able to change **Reply-To** email id. Here, I've added `$mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Reply');`. But, it doesn't shows the emailid(contact form sender emailid) in Reply-To option.

[image]

I've posted an image here. In quick reply option i can see the receiveing end email id. How can i add a reply to email id(contact form sender emailid)?

```
<?php
require_once('phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$name = trim($_POST["name"]);
$typeofmotor = trim($_POST["typeofmotor"]);
$email = trim($_POST["email"]);
$mail->IsSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';                         // Specify main and backup server
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'email@gmail.com';  // SMTP username
$mail->Password = '1234567890';                  // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress('email@gmail.com', '');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Reply');
$mail->AddBCC('');
$mail->WordWrap = 50;      
$mail->IsHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
$mail->Subject = 'subject name';
$mail->Body    =  "<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang='en-us'>
            <head>
                <meta charset='utf-8'>
                <title></title>
            </head>
            <body>
                <table width=550 style=\"border: 1px solid #333333;\" border=0 align=center cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>
                </table>
            </body>
    <html>";

if(!$mail->Send()) 
{
   echo 'Message could not be sent.';
   echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   exit;
}
else
{
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Message has been sent"); </script>';
    echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "contact.php"; </script>';

}
?>
```

Comment: try to set replyto before fromName see what happens. just a suggestion not sure if it works.

Comment: @Marius.C : nope. not working...

Comment: xdebug it. see where that $mail->AddReplyTo() is doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress('email@gmail.com', '');  // Add a recipient
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Reply');
```

Try to use this:

```
$mail->AddReplyTo($email, 'Reply');
$mail->SetFrom('mailbox@name.com', 'Mailbox name');
$mail->AddAddress('email@gmail.com', '');
```

**Notice:**
the reply to addresses needed to be added before the from address

Comment: i tried this one. but, still not getting the sender email id in reply to option..